Prevent installed apps from opening the Microsoft store
I've installed Net Speed Meter from the Microsoft Store https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9nmbx01pxz4l on my Windows 11 computer. Now, when I restart my computer, the Microsoft Store opens to the Net Speed Monitor Plus page, inviting me to pay to upgrade. How do I disable this behavior?

Have you looked to find how the process is being started, or what is starting it? Places to check are the MSconfig or Task Manager startup sections or AutoRuns (by Microsoft's Sysinternals), and ProcessExplorer (also by Sysinternals) to see the full argument for the running Store process. This info is likely to be helpful. You should also check the app's Settings to see if it has an option there that may control this behavior.

Because UWP apps (like the store itself) are so different, it is unlikely the command line would be helpful. // Net Speed Meter would be launching a URL.

Looking at the Microsoft Store web page, it would be, more specifically, a ms-windows-store URL, like ms-windows-store://pdp?hl=en-us&gl=us&referrer=storeforweb&productid=9nrwmjp3717k&ocid=storeweb-pdp-open-cta (Python 3.11).

I checked the command line in ProcessExplorer and see "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_22405.1401.9.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WinStore.App.exe" -ServerName:App.AppXc75wvwned5vhz4xyxxecvgdjhdkgsdza.mca. This seems to be a standard execution for the store so, as @DanielB suggests, it may not be helpful. It may be that the app is launching that URL. How to stop it?
